# The Unity launcher panel disappears after a second

Tags: unity, mouse, launcher

Today I gave up on starting Firefox using the launcher because every time I moved the mouse pointer to the left edge of the screen, the launcher panel appeared, and immediately disappeared again (with the usual sliding motion).
I never had the chance to move the pointer to the Firefox launcher button to activate it.

Now that I have Firefox running full-screen, when I move the pointer to the left edge, nothing happens. If I slide the pointer along the left edge, a gray fringe appears briefly, but no launcher panel.

But now that I am writing about it, and trying again, after a couple tries, the panel appears if I slide the pointer fast enough and also far enough. And now, once the panel shows, it does stay put until I move the pointer out of the launcher entirely. If I slide too slowly or to short a distance, at most I get the gray fringe described in the second paragraph.

I now also tried to minimize all windows to see if I got the behavior I described in the first paragraph, but no, I still have the behavior of the third paragraph.

This is not the first time I experience this. It's been countless times before. Quite possibly it happens only when I have just logged in. Yet I have not found anyone else asking about this.

The behavior described in the first paragraph is annoying, how can I fix it?

Comment: what is actually an issue? You want the Launcher to unhide and stay or remove this option? or you want to change the speed it appears?

Answer (score 1):

In *System Settings* select *Appearance* and then go to *Behavior* tab to modify the launcher auto-hide settings. Probably, what you want to adjust is the sensitivity option.

A 3rd party application *Unity Tweak Tool* has even more options for launcher's settings.
Unity Tweak Tool can be acquired via `apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`. You will most likely need administrative permission, thus `sudo` before `apt-get` should be added.
Open the Unity Tweak Tool and locate *Launcher* under *Unity* category.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem here as well on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Solution 1:
Turning off Auto-hide (System Settings -> Appearance -> Behavior -> Auto-hide the Launcher)
Solution 2:
Logging off and on again

Would like to know the reason for the problem, however.